# How to use Google Analytics setAllowAnchor flag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to get the [setAllowAnchor flag in Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor) to record campaign information but it doesn't seem to be working.

The site I'm trying to use it on uses hashbang-style URLs BTW - that's the `http://hostname/#!/relative-url` style of navigation because there needs to be a persistant audio player across page views.

I've tried both of the below, but am not seeing any `setAllowAnchor` campaign in GA.

```
/#!/&utm_campaign=setAllowAnchor&utm_medium=hash&utm_source=test
/#utm_campaign=setAllowAnchor&utm_medium=hash&utm_source=test
```

The function setAllowAnchor is not deprecated. What am I doing wrong?

My Google Analytics code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1060190-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any Google Analytics configuration must come before the `_trackPageview` or any other `_track*` functions. So if you rewrite your code to issue the `_setAllowAnchor` before the `_trackPageview` it should work.

Also notice that `_trackPageLoadTime` is not needed anymore. It's [issued by default](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageLoadTime) and so ths function is deprecated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1060190-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Do we still need this with their newest version `analytics.js` ? Apparently yes : "Note: if the anchor portion of the URL contains campaign parameters, those parameters get kept in the anchor and sent to Google Analytics for processing (unless the allowAnchor field is set to false). "  [source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)